# How to disable Keycloak SSL when running Keycloak in Docker?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot application and in that I have done Keycloak integration with my REST API.
Now I want to build a Docker image for my app to host in the cloud.

First I tried:

```
docker container run -d -p 8081:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak
```

That was not working; I couldn't open the login screen for Keycloak.
So I tried this:

```
docker container run -p 8443:8443 -d -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak
```

Using this now I can login to Keycloak.

Then I tried disabling SSL in `Realm->Login` tab.
I can do this as this is my development environment and I am not much worried about SSL.

Is there any option of disabling SSL while running Keycloak in Docker?
If not how I can disable it?

If it is not possible to disable SSL in Keycloak while running on Docker, how can I integrate the SSL connection of Keycloak with the Spring Boot REST API?

Comment: How did you try to access the login screen? If I run your original command verbatim, it works just fine. I can point my browser at `http://localhost:8081` and access the keycloak ui.

Comment: Do you know that https is mandatory for OIDC? Why do you want to sacrifice security in the free TLS cert world (Let's Encrypt)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to run a reverse proxy in front of Keycloak anyway, `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` is what you're looking for.

This will disable the TLS requirement if you also send `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` in the  header.

Running without TLS at all is not supported.

Documented here:

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/server/README.md#enabling-proxy-address-forwarding

Answer (score 1):

Update the `REALM` table to disable requiring SSL by :

```
UPDATE REALM SET SSL_REQUIRED='NONE' WHERE ID=<RECORD_ID>;
```